# Extract text layer from PSD ( ImageMagick or GiMP )

Tags: command-line, imagemagick, gimp

I want to extract text infos from layer ( like font, font-style, font-size and content ) with the name and number of layer.

All available command line on standard repo are an option.

I know it can be done from Photoshop scripting, but for the sake of science I would like to do it from a Unix server, and maybe later extract all infos from multiple file in a zip and process them with multiple tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIMP has the script-fu scheme extension that can be run from the command line.  This will be sketchy because I have not written any scheme in some 3-4 years, but here goes nothing:

Assuming the following script in a file called `sc.sch`:

```
(define (go-by-layers no layers)
  (while (< 0 no)
    (let* ((layer (vector-ref layers (- no 1))))
      (display "Layer name: ")
      (display (car (gimp-item-get-name layer))) (newline)
      (if (< 0 (car (gimp-item-is-text-layer layer)))
          (begin
            (display "This is a text layer") (newline)
            (display "Font: ")
            (display (car (gimp-text-layer-get-font layer))) (newline)
            (display "Text: ")
            (display (car (gimp-text-layer-get-text layer))) (newline)
          ) )
      (if (>= 0 (car (gimp-item-is-text-layer layer)))
          (begin
            (display "Not a text layer")
            (newline)
          ) )
      (set! no (- no 1))
    )
  )
)
(let* ((layers (gimp-image-get-layers 1)))
  (display "Number of Layers: ") (display (car layers)) (newline)
  (go-by-layers (car layers) (cadr layers))
  (display "end") (newline)
)
(gimp-quit 0)
```

We can do:

```
$ gimp zz.psd -b - < sc.sch 2>/dev/null
Welcome to TinyScheme, Version 1.40
Copyright (c) Dimitrios Souflis

ts> go-by-layers
ts> Number of Layers: 2
Layer name: Background
Not a text layer
Layer name: Layer 1
Not a text layer
end
#t
```

This is quite hacky since we are running the batch mode from STDIN and redirecting the script in.  We also get the prompt output, which is quite ugly, but should work with most GIMP versions.

How does this work:

- Since we have only one image loaded we know it is named `1`.
- We get the layers with `(gimp-image-get-layers 1)`
- The layers are a fixed vector so we walk through them using `vector-ref` (inside a `while`)
- `(gimp-item-is-text-layer layer)` provides us with information whether we can execute text specific operations on the layer.
- `gimp-text-layer-get-*` give us info about the text layer.
- For non-text layers we print less info.

How to get a function reference for script-fu?

In GIMP go to `Filters -> Script Fu -> Console`.  And in there, next to the text field where you can insert scheme commands, you get a button `Browse` that gets the reference for you version of GIMP.

Disclaimer: this is poorly tested, I only have a simple two layer (without any text) PSD to test it.

Comment: Problem is that GIMP doesn't import text layers in PSD files as text layers yet. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151686